# How to pass parameters from view to controller in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a button called **search** in the view file **search**.I want to pass **stop,stops** from view to controller action called **search**.
Code is given below:

view:

```
  <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['search','stop'=>$model->stop,'stops'=>$model->stops], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Controller:

```
    public function actionSearch($stop,$stops)
    {
    print_r($stop);die();
    }
```

But it shows the error:

```
 PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

 Undefined variable: stop
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Try to access using $_REQUEST variable .

Comment: And it is also possible $model->stop and $model->stops contain Null . so you cant get value. I tried using static value and it worked fine !

Comment: K.Thank you Yasin Patel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**view:**

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['search','stop'=>$stop,'stops'=>$stops], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

**controller:**

```
public function actionSearch($stop,$stops)
{
    return $this->render('search', ['stop' => $stop, 'stops' => $stops]);
}
```

Comment: stop and stops are two fileds in the view "search".I need $stop,$stops in the controller action "search" after clicking the "search" button.

Comment: I think that you will send stop and stops fields using post, from search action. Is it right?

Comment: No.I am sending stop,stops to search action from search view after render the same view from another action called create.